# Safari: Download a file if uri scheme could not find app

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, ms-word, uri

I want to launch Microsoft Word when a file link is clicked and if MS Word could not be launched then download the file instead. The [blur hack](https://gist.github.com/aaronk6/d801d750f14ac31845e8#file-launch_uri-js) method is working fine in Chrome and IE but in Safari; it launches another modal if the uri scheme could not find an app meaning word was not installed in the machine. So, the blur hack method will not work. Uri scheme for word looks like this: `ms-word:ofv|u|{the file link/path}`